# why win7>0 then add new stylesheet don't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add extra stylesheets into head element. I used below code in console and it does the work but if i put it into my .js file, it won't add the stylesheet. I already made sure jQuery loads before js file. Do I have to make it a self executed function by adding (); after closing bracket? I thought window.load will run while page is loading...

```
var winxp = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 5.1');
var winvs = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.0');
var win7 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.1');
var win8 = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows NT 6.2');
window.onload = function () {
    if ($(winxp > 0) || $(winvs > 0) || $(win7 > 0) || $(win8 > 0)) {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fontello-windows.css?3" />').insertAfter('head');
    };
}
```

Comment: Everything you need to know: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: `$(winxp > 0)`...? That's a new one on me...

Comment: Joe Conlin, the added stylesheet is not only for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to self execute functions in `window.onload`:

Self Execution:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if ($(winxp > 0) || $(winvs > 0) || $(win7 > 0) || $(win8 > 0)) {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fontello-windows.css?3" />').insertAfter('head');
    };
}();
```

Or with function:

```
function checkWin() {
    if ($(winxp > 0) || $(winvs > 0) || $(win7 > 0) || $(win8 > 0)) {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/fontello-windows.css?3" />').insertAfter('head');
    };
}

window.onload = checkWin();
```

Check out this [tutorial](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/) for more details

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'd like to click the up arrow for you but I am newbie here and dont have enough points